# css:hover:after on another element

Tags: css

I still struggle with having css:hover apply to another element on the page.

Upon hovering over a menu element ('.sub-menu'), I'd like to have a grey overlay appear over the content of the page ('.overlay'). So how do I make it so that .sub-menu:hover causes .overlay to appear?

Thing is, the html isn't anywhere close to each other. Though .sub-menu does come before .overlay, so it's in the right order.

I've made the overlay like this:

```
.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
  background: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.overlay:hover:after  {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: You need to show your html structure to see if it is possible with css - you may need some js if they are nowhere near each other

Comment: Can you provide HTML ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. They are nowhere near. I'm using a template that I'm trying to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overlay independent from the content of your page, positioned as a sibling after the menu so you can reference it with the `~` general sibling combinator, then position that overlay as a fixed `height:100vh` `width:100vw`, considering the right Z-indexes.

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:10;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  opacity:0;
  background: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu{
  position:relative;
  z-index:20
}

.menu:hover ~ .overlay {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu">hover me!</button>
<div class="overlay"></div>

<h1>some content</h1>
<p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
```

Edit: as adding elements is not an option, you can get away with pseudo-elements. 
Important stuff here is that you need to set the :hover::before to pointer-events:none; otherwise the overlay will not disappear when you move out of the button.

```css
.menu{
  position:relative;
}

.menu::before {
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background: grey;
  transition: 0.2s;
  display:none;
}


.menu:hover::before {
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.9;
  display:block;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="menu">hover me!</button>
<h1>some content</h1>

<p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but that means I'd have to edit the template by adding a div before the content. Was hoping to avoid that, seeing as it's not a child theme and will be removed whenever it updates.

Comment: @DennisDekker I've added an alternative based on a pseudo-element, I think that will work for you

Comment: It did! Thanks for your help!